# Velocity - Delete fields when can't be merged

Tags: velocity

I use velocity to merge a String(template) with field like

```
hi there I'am ${name},
And I'am ${age} old.
```

velocity merged the field `${name}` and `${age}` with a kind of hashtable:

```
velocityEngine.evaluate(context, writer, "", template);
```

`context` is the hashtable(or better a `VelocityContext` type)

I want when Velocity can't find the field in the context he just delete them.

can i do this with a property or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is what you are asking, but if you want to prevent unassigned template vars from showing up in merged templates, you can use [quiet notation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#quietreferencenotation) by writing `$!{name}`, there is also a global setting for that.